# How to access object's constructor in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, oop, constructor, prototype

I have this piece of code:

```
var MyConstructor = function(){};
var MyObject = new MyConstructor();
```

What I noticed is `MyObject.constructor` is not pointing to `MyConstructor`. So what is the standard way of accessing the constructor of an object from the object itself?

I need this to access constructor's prototype properties like `MyConstructor.prototype = {mykey : "value"}`. I can access `mykey` this way: `MyConstructor.prototype.mykey` but `MyObject.constructor.prototype.mykey` is not defined.

Here is the complete code and their output using jsconsole.com:

```
var MyConstructor = function(){};
MyConstructor.prototype = {mykey : "value"};
var MyObject = new MyConstructor();

MyObject.mykey; // output: "value"
MyConstructor.prototype.mykey; // output: "value"
MyObject.constructor.prototype.mykey; // output: undefined
MyObject.constructor === MyConstructor; // output: false
MyObject.constructor.prototype.mykey === "value";  // output: false
```

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks for the reply, I did. I used jsconsole.com to test this. Can the site be responsible for the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you change the prototype property of `MyConstructor`. That means that `MyObject` is created from *that* object and does not get the `constructor` property that the original prototype object had. So in your test case, `MyObject.constructor === Object`, since that is the constructor that is used for the object literal `{mykey: "value"}`.

To avoid this behaviour, don't *assign* a new object to the `prototype` property, but *mutate* the existing one:

```js
var MyConstructor = function(){};
MyConstructor.prototype.mykey = "value";
var MyObject = new MyConstructor();

console.log(
  MyObject.mykey, // output: "value"
  MyConstructor.prototype.mykey, // output: "value"
  MyObject.constructor.prototype.mykey, // output: "value"
  MyObject.constructor === MyConstructor, // output: true
  MyObject.constructor.prototype.mykey === "value",  // output: true
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.getPrototypeOf(MyObject).mykey` gets the prototype directly from MyObject.

[Mozilla developer link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)